# Ubuntu Budgie - panel displays while in Full-Screen mode

Tags: gnome, 17.04, budgie, ubuntu-budgie

I am trying to test some games in Ubuntu Budgie. I can neither hide the side-panel on the left, or the top-panel whilst in game.

Is there a way to automatically hide these in full-screen mode?

How can I do this? It's obscuring the game and it's very annoying :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Budgie 10.4 release, there is a stand alone settings application for Budgie Desktop. It provides option to set the visibility of panels.
[image]

See automatically hide option in **Budgie Settings**

---

Ubuntu Budgie 17.04 comes with Budgie Desktop 10.2.9. You can update to Budgie Desktop 10.4 using backports repository provided by Ubuntu Budgie team.

In command line, it can be done as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntubudgie/backports
sudo apt update
sudo apt install budgie-desktop
```

For more on installation of Budgie 10.4 on Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 and 17.04 see [original blog post](https://ubuntubudgie.org/blog/2017/08/28/budgie-desktop-v10-4-released-for-debian-and-ubuntu) shared by Ubuntu Budgie team.